# Написать функцию формы авторизации на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, авторизация

Есть задание: Написать функцию авторизации.
Например: чтобы логин и пароль совпадали допустим(логин: admin123, и пароль:admin123), и если пользователь вводит верный пароль и логин ему выводит сообщение, по типу "Добро пожаловать" если пользователь вводит пароль или логин неправильно, то выводит сообщение, по типу "Вход недоступен" и вызывается input, чтобы человек ввел верный пароль или логин.

Comment: с Вас 40 гривен.

Comment: Помощь - это вы пишите код, мы направляем и советуем. Вы хотите, чтоб вам не помогли, а за вас код написали =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычная задача, что именно у вас не получается?